# No module named 'pandas' auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, module, pyinstaller, exe, auto-py-to-exe

I have a problem when I want to convert my python script into executables file. The problem is the external module such as `pandas`, `numpy`, `scikit-learn` was not imported. I know it caused I need to create the python environment first. But in my case, I need to convert this script into an executable without python installation, so I just to run the .exe file and use it. I have using pyinstaller, and auto-py-to-exe. None of those work.

How can I convert my python script that has external modules into executables file? Is there any way to do that? without creating a python environment? Or any reference related of this?

Comment: yes...  pyinstaller is capable of compiling an exe with external librarys create a [example]

Answer (score 0):

If you have pyinstaller installed in your current python environment with all the packages required by your script then nothing more is needed, Go ahead and run pyinstaller.

`pyinstaller myscript.py`

Essential reading : https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html